# Any generalized formula for the number of times "Anjali" will be printed?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, iteration

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int n;

    printf("Input a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i *= 3)
        for (int j = i; j <= n; j++)
            printf("Anjali \n");

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to generate a formula for the number of times `printf()` is executed.

Example: When **n** = 10;

`printf()` is executed 20 times

Comment: Yes there is a formula. Why would you need one? A homework?

Comment: Na, I am preparing for **GATE** exam and stucked at this point.

Comment: How many times will the outer loop run? Begin with that. Then use it to calculate the inner loop.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude according to me outer loop will run [ floor(logn) + 1 ] base of log is 3.

Comment: maybe write something counting those printfs (you do not need to print it) https://godbolt.org/z/TGso3ao1T and then try to find the rule (hint:> id increases by 2 then by 3 then by 4 ....)

Comment: Use `#include <stdio.h>`, not `#include "stdio.h"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `for (int i = 1; i <= n; i *= 3)`, *i* takes on the values of 3<sup>*k*</sup> for non-negative integers *k* such that 3<sup>*k*</sup> ≤ *n*, hence *k* ≤ log<sub>3</sub> *n*, so *k* takes on the values 0, 1,… ⌊log<sub>3</sub> *n*⌋. (⌊*x*⌋ is the floor of *x*, the greatest integer not greater than *x*. Also, we assume *n* is positive.)

In each iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop `for (int j = i; j <= n; j++)` is executed, resulting in the `printf` being executed *n*−*i*+1 times. In an iteration of the outer loop, *i* is 3<sup>*k*</sup>, so, over all the iterations of the outer loop, `printf` is executed sum(*n*−3<sup>*k*</sup>+1 for 0 ≤ *k* ≤ ⌊log<sub>3</sub> *n*⌋) times.

This sum is (*n*+1)•(⌊log<sub>3</sub> *n*⌋+1) − sum(3<sup>*k*</sup> for 0 ≤ *k* ≤ ⌊log<sub>3</sub> *n*⌋). The latter term is a geometric sequence whose sum is (3<sup>⌊log<sub>3</sub> *n*⌋+1</sup>−1)/(3−1). So the `printf` is executed (*n*+1)•(⌊log<sub>3</sub> *n*⌋+1) − (3<sup>⌊log<sub>3</sub> *n*⌋+1</sup>−1)/2 times.